# overriding rails active record destroy unexpected deletion of has_and_belongs_to_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inheritance, super, destroy

I have a Commentable class that inherits from ActiveRecord::Base and an Event class that inherits from Commentables.

I have overwritten the destroy methods in both of these classes, and Event.distroy calls super. However, some unexpected things happen. Specifically, the Event's has_and_belongs_to_many associations are deleted. I think this is happening because some modules are getting included between the Commentables and the Event class, but not sure if there is a way to stop this.

Here's the simplified code:

```
class Commentable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments

  def destroy
    comments.destroy_all
    self.deleted = true
    self.save!
  end

end

class Event < Commentable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :practitioners, :foreign_key => "commentable_id"

  def destroy
    #some Event specific code
    super
  end

end
```

I don't want to delete the rows from the database, just set a "deleted" flag. Nor do I want to delete any of the associations. However, somewhere between the Event.destroy and the Commentable.destroy, some other rails code destroys the record in the has_and_belongs_to_many table.

Any idea why this is happening and how to stop it?

Answer (score 5):

You don't really have to override destroy on `Commentable` model, just add a `before_destroy` callback that return `false` to actually cancels the destroy call. For example:

```
class Commentable < ActiveRecord::Base
 # ... some code ...
  before_destroy { |record|
    comments.destroy_all
    self.deleted = true
    self.save!
    false
  }
 # ... some code ...
 end
```

The same goes for `Event` model; just add a callback without overriding the destroy method itself.

More on the available callbacks is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 doesn't halt callback chain if `false` is returned. We'll have to use `throw(:abort)` instead.

```
before_destroy :destroy_validation

def destroy_validation
  if condition
    errors.add(:base, "item cannot be destroyed because of the reason...")
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

Before Rails 5, returning `false` from any `before_ callback` in `ActiveModel or ActiveModel::Validations, ActiveRecord` & `ActiveSupport` resulted in halting of callback chain.

We can turn off this default behavior by changing this configuration to `true`. However then Rails shows deprecation warning when `false` is returned from callback.

The new Rails 5 application comes up with an initializer named `callback_terminator.rb`.

```
ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false
```

By default the value is to set to `false`.

```
=> DEPRECATION WARNING: Returning `false` in Active Record and Active Model callbacks will not implicitly halt a callback chain in the next release of Rails. To explicitly halt the callback chain, please use `throw :abort` instead.
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: Failed to save the record
```

This is a welcome change that will help prevent accidental halting of the callbacks.